# airflow - Dags are not being executed on scheduled time

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I wanted to have my dags to have first run on `2:00 AM on 25th` and then onwards Tuesday to Sat daily run at `2:00 am`.

following is how my scheduling look like.

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id='in__xxx__agnt_brk_com',
    schedule_interval='0 2 * * 2-6',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 10, 24),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
```

And on Airflow UI also it shows that my first run should be on `25th 2:00 AM`. But unfortunately, dags didn't execute on time.

[image]
[image]

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is scheduling at 2am in your local time, that is 6am in UTC.

Take a look at this link on how to specify the timezone in your dag: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html

Comment: and in UTC time also, it's past `25th 2:00 AM`. it's not the timezone issue, I understand.

Comment: Please be clear with what you expect to happen and what you are experiencing

Comment: it's there as part of the question. `I wanted to have my dags to have first run on 2:00 AM on 25th and then onwards Tuesday to Sat daily run at 2:00 am` but the dag has not executed on 25th.

Comment: Could you share more information on the DAG status, is it on pause? If you change the dag as to run inmediately, does it run?

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the documentation on [dag intervals](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#data-interval).

Your dag did not run on the 25th:

- Your start date is 2022-10-24

This creates a dag interval of 2022-10-24 - 2022-10-25.

- You set `catchup=False`

You created the dag after midnight on the 25th. The dag interval for the 24th has passed and you've denied catchup.

- The next dag is scheduled for 2022-10-25

This creates a dag interval of 2022-10-25 - 2022-10-26

Your dag will run at 2am UTC on the 26th.